# ::after and ::before elements absolute positioned don't stick to very bottom of body

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm going nuts! lol
I'm trying to position one image to the bottom of a page but it only works if the page is on large width...say 1360px, but when I shrink the with exactly to the 1206px and less, the body the image is pushed up creating a padding to the bottom as you can see in the image bellow (The image is represented by the green box). [image]

The green image is positioned using this CSS:

```
    body::after {
    content: "";
    width: 556px;
    height: 767px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 10%;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("imagens/ghost-dog.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

And also there is a transparency (this purplish shadow) I added using other property that don't sticky to the bottom too. Using this CSS:

```
    body::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

And last to make my mind go round and round there is a background to the body but it fits ALL screen as expected:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: "comfortaa-regular";
    background-color: var(--cor-roxa);
    background-image: url("imagens/logo-bg.svg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I've already tried to position body relative, but it didn't solve the issue. I don't know if it matter but I'm using bootstrap and my divs are organized like the image below:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Proper [mre], or it didn’t happen.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any example to review this is difficult to determine a cause. That said, what immediately comes to mind is a child element with a margin is overflowing it's parent container pushing the window boundary but not it's parent containers boundary.

I would inspect your elements and toggle any margins to see if this has any effect.

If you add your code to a fiddle I can take a look and update this if I notice the issue.